# How can I check the content of the FolderBrowserDialog if is it empty or not?

Tags: c#, wpf, folderbrowserdialog

I'm using `FolderBrowserDialog` in a WPF project and it works fine, I would like to check the content of the folder selected `selectedPath` if is it empty or null and the extension of the existed files.

How can I do that?

```
try
{
    using (var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        FileText.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
    }
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error : " + exp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK || result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        FileText.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
        var directory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dialog.SelectedPath);

        var files = directory.GetFiles(); // Array with information about files.

        if (files.Length == 0)
            Debug.WriteLine("Empty Folder.");
        else
        {
            var filesTxt = files.Where(f => f.Extension == ".txt").ToArray(); // Array with information about TXT files.
            if (filesTxt.Length == 0)
                Debug.WriteLine("There is no TXT files in the folder.");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this work with the other extensions or only with .txt files?

Comment: With any extension.
Plain string comparison.